# Failing to set up a log formatter class instance using Faust

Tags: python-3.x, django, python-logging, faust

Im trying to add a class of log formatter to the faust `logging_config` but getting an error with not mush exlained:

```
CANNOT SETUP LOGGING: ValueError("Unable to configure formatter 'exp_formatter'") from   File "det_to_events/main.py", line 246, in <module>
    app.main()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faust/app/base.py", line 761, in main
    cli(app=self)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 26, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faust/cli/base.py", line 539, in _inner
    cmd()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faust/cli/base.py", line 620, in __call__
    self.run_using_worker(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faust/cli/base.py", line 630, in run_using_worker
    raise worker.execute_from_commandline()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/worker.py", line 279, in execute_from_commandline
    self.loop.run_until_complete(self._starting_fut)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 84, in run_until_complete
    self._run_once()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 120, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/events.py", line 81, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/nest_asyncio.py", line 196, in step
    step_orig(task, exc)
  File "/opt/homebrew/opt/python@3.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/asyncio/tasks.py", line 280, in __step
    result = coro.send(None)
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 800, in start
    await self._default_start()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 807, in _default_start
    await self._actually_start()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/services.py", line 815, in _actually_start
    await self.on_first_start()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/faust/worker.py", line 334, in on_first_start
    await self.default_on_first_start()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/worker.py", line 178, in default_on_first_start
    self._setup_logging()
  File "/Users/matany/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/det-to-events-S0HiGbUI-py3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mode/worker.py", line 201, in _setup_logging
    traceback.print_stack(file=self.stderr)
```

my code:

```
from my_package_path import MyLogger

my_config = {
    'version': 1,
    "disable_existing_loggers": False,
    'formatters': {
         "exp_formatter": {"()": 'path.to.my.formatter', "format": "EXPERIMENTAL log formatter - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s"},
        
    },
    'handlers': {
        'root_logger_handler': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'level': 'INFO',
            'formatter': "exp_formatter"
        }
    },
     'loggers': {
         '': {
            'level': 'INFO',
            'handlers': ['root_logger_handler']
         },
     }
}
```

This configuration is added to `Faust` logging_config and later i call `app.main()`, where i get the error.
I can also tell that when im trying to serialize the configuration using `json.dumps(my_config)` im getting an error saying that the object is not serlizable, so it might be connected as well.

Help would be appreciated!